# How to merge subarray values and remove duplicates?

Tags: php, arrays, unique, flatten, array-merge

```
$arr[] = array('A','B');
$arr[] = array('C','B');
...
```

I need to get the merged result of all sub array of `$arr` .

And for duplicated entries,should fetch only one.

Answer (score 25):

If you really don't want to loop, try this:

```
$arr[] = array('A','B');
$arr[] = array('C','B');
$arr[] = array('C','D');
$arr[] = array('F','A');
$merged = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr));
```

Comment: I think there is no need for `array_unique` as `array_merge` will overwrite duplicate keys if found any. Can anybody please reply me?

Comment: without the 'array_merge' the following error comes up "ErrorException: call_user_func_array() expects exactly 2 parameters" @Ankit

Comment: genius, one of the rare cases when we can actually use call_user_func_array and it's like a perfect fit for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 15):

OK through another question I found out that the following is actually possible (I tried myself without success, I had the wrong version) if you use **PHP version >= 5.3.0**:

```
$merged_array = array_reduce($arr, 'array_merge', array());
```

---

If you only want unique values you can apply [`array_unique`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
$unique_merged_array = array_unique($merged_array);
```

This works if you only have flat elements in the arrays (i.e. no other arrays). From the documentation:

> **Note:** Note that `array_unique()` is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.

If you have arrays in your arrays then you have to check manually e.g. with [`array_walk`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
$unique_values = array();

function unique_value($value, &$target_array) {
    if(!in_array($value, $target_array, true))
        $target_array[] = $value;
}

array_walk($merged_values, 'unique_value', $unique_values);
```

I think one can assume that the internal loops (i.e. what `array_walk` is doing) are at least **not** slower than explicit loops.

Comment: I don't think $merged_array = array_merge($arr); will actually break up the sub-arrays, which I'm pretty sure is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Worth noting that array_merge should be in quotes e.g. 'array_merge'

Answer (score 8):

```
array_unique(array_merge($arr[0], $arr[1]));
```

or for an unlimited case, I think this should work:

```
$result_arr = array();
foreach ($arr as $sub_arr) $result_arr = array_merge($result_arr, $sub_arr);
$result_arr = array_unique($result_arr);
```

Comment: It can have more than 2 sub arrays.

Comment: The number of sub arrays is dynamic.

Comment: Despite the author only giving $arr 0 + 1 as an example, I think they needs a solution to accommodate for all child items of $arr.

Comment: Is there a way to do it other than loop?

Comment: why? what's wrong with a loop? I suppose you could use some kind of mapping function. Look at the array section of the php docs for other ideas. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: If the number of arrays are dynamic, I think loops could be the best choice. Why would you not want a loop?

Comment: Is there a array function that can handle this problem?

Comment: array_walk() is a possibility, but it's more overhead

Comment: It is still not correct, it has to be `$result_arr = array_merge($result_arr, $sub_arr);`

Answer (score 1):

$merged_array = array_reduce($serp_res, 'array_merge', array()); 
with added quotas,'array_merge', worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on Felix Kling post.
It's more accurate version with fixing "non array" sub-elements.

```
$res = array_reduce($res, function(&$res, $v) {
                            return array_merge($res, (array) $v);
                        }, array());
```

Comment: Great solution and use array_filter() to get rid of empty array elements caused by empty array values or strings added previously. Here is the final version: $res = array_filter(array_reduce($res, function(&$res, $v) {return array_merge($res, (array) $v);}, array()));

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 5.6 with splat operator:

```
array_unique(array_merge(...$arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to handle this in PHP Version `>= 5.6` is to use the splat operator also called [Argument Unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking).

```
$arr = array_unique(array_merge(...$arr));
```