# PHP: Merge array by defining parent array only?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to do this in PHP:

```
$a['foo'] = [1,2,3];
$a['bar'] = [4,5,6];
```

Instead of `array_merge($a['foo'], $a['bar'])`, you would use simply use something like `array_merge($a)` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge subarray in PHP most easily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140503/how-to-merge-subarray-in-php-most-easily)

Comment: `$a['foo]'` is it intentional or is it a typo?

Comment: you can write a function for that. is it always foo and bar?

Comment: Also possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041278/php-how-to-merge-arrays-inside-array ?

Comment: @Nordenheim typo thanks, fixed.

Comment: You mean like what array_merge_recursive() does? (it would have been helpful if you had provided an example of your expected output).

Answer (score 1):

**[Live demo](http://ideone.com/EhqRM4)**

```
function my_array_merge($array) {
   $result = [];
   foreach($array as $subArray) {
      $result = array_merge($result, $subArray);
   }
   return $result;
}
```