# PHP - add one array to another (recursively?)

Tags: php

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = array(
  'currencies' => array(
    'dollars' => array(80,120,75),
    'euro' => array(25,35,10,85),
  ),
);

$array2 = array(
  'currencies' => array(
    'dollars' => array(25),
  ),
);
```

I would like the result to be:

```
$result = array(
  'currencies' => array(
    'dollars' => array(80,120,75,25),
    'euro' => array(25,35,10,85),
  ),
);
```

Can this be accomplished in a clever way? I have tried array_merge, array_merge_recursively etc.

Comment: I guess this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140503/how-to-merge-subarray-in-php-most-easily

Comment: Did you try [array_merge_recursive()](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge-recursive.php)? This is not what you want?

Comment: did you really try `array_merge_recursively()`? https://3v4l.org/AkeFu

Answer (score 5):

how did you try with [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive)? Because this works good for me:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
  'currencies' => array(
    'dollars' => array(80,120,75),
    'euro' => array(25,35,10,85),
  ),
);

$array2 = array(
  'currencies' => array(
    'dollars' => array(25),
  ),
);

var_dump(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));
```